# Function acting funny on resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this banner ticker which works as you first load the page, but it gets messed up as you resize the second time and my assumption is that I am not calling the function in the right way on the resize event, any advice so I can understand what is going on?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/carlozdre/Hwpf9/)

html

```
<div class="">
    <div class="topBanners" style="float: left; width: 200px; ">
        <p>First one</p>
    </div>
    <div class="topBanners" style="float: left; width: 200px; ">
        <p>Second</p>
    </div>
    <div class="topBanners" style="float: left; width: 200px; ">
        <p>Third</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    currentTopBanner = 0;
    var topBanners = $('.topBanners');

    console.log(topBanners.length);

    function rotateTopBanners() {

        if ($(window).width() < 768) {
            topBanners.hide();
            $(topBanners[currentTopBanner]).fadeIn('slow').delay(100).fadeOut('slow');
            $(topBanners[currentTopBanner]).queue(function () {
                currentTopBanner = currentTopBanner < topBanners.length - 1 ? currentTopBanner + 1 : 0;
                rotateTopBanners();
                $(this).dequeue();
            });
        } else {
            topBanners.show();
        }
    }

    rotateTopBanners();


    $(window).resize(function () {
        rotateTopBanners();
    });

});
```

Comment: Couldn't `$(window).resize(function () { rotateTopBanners(); });` be just `$(window).resize(rotateTopBanners);` ?

Comment: of course, I am calling a few more functions on the resize event and have only modified/deleted parts of the code so I can show it and left it like that; there's no change in behaviour anyway